# Issue with VM arguments length in Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to launch a webapp locally in my eclipse (3.7) using Tomcat (5.5.26). I have to supply a lot of arguments for this webapp in the "open launch configuration -> arguments" tab. Strangely, the server startup fails as soon as the argument lenght exceeds 512 characters. Does anyone know how to overwrite this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with VM arguments here. We use Ivy for dependency resolution and the IVY HOME is set to some path deep and as the project had a lot of dependencies the overall IVY path became much longer than the accepted limit. I have changed the IVY HOME to something closer to C drive and it solved the problem.